# Wrong colors while using karnaugh-map package with MikTex and TexMaker

Tags: miktex, texmaker, karnaugh

I am super noob with LaTeX so far, so I am not sure if this is a bug with something on my setup or I am missing something extremely obvious.

I have MikTex with TexMaker setup on my Windows 10 machine and I am testing the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}

\begin{document}
    \begin{karnaugh-map}
    \implicant{5}{15}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

What can go wrong, right?

I compiled this code with two different TexMaker "Quick Build" commands. One is generating `.dvi` and `.pdf` (1) and another - only `pdf` (2).

(1) is preferred for me because I wish to convert TikZ pictures in `.dvi` into `.SVG` formats using `dvisvgm input.dvi output.svg` to upload to my website.

But (1) gives me incorrect output in the pdf preview, but after `dvisvgm input.dvi output.svg`, the output `.SVG` is correct. Here's the incorrect `pdf` preview with option (1):
[image]

(2) gives correct `pdf` preview:
[image]

Now, what's going on?

Comment: a dvi can be processed by dvips+ps2pdf, dvipdfmx and dvisvg. Every route needs different code and specials. Depending on what you plan you have to add driver options so that the code knows what you are planing (the default route is dvips+ps2pdf, this doesn't need an option).

Comment: So, what exactly would I need to add to get it output correctly then?

Comment: I don't have texmaker and don't know what your button is doing. Perhaps you need `dvipdfmx` or `dvipdfm`. But imho this will then clash with your svg call. So probably best is to use (2) to get the pdf, and (1) if you want to create a svg.